# grid in telerik controls, change column value

Tags: linq, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

This is my telerik code where the column text should be if Column value IsApproveReject = 0 then it should be pending, if 1 then approved, if 2 then rejected text should be come.
How can i achieve this in linq syntax.

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{columns.Bound(typeof(int), "IsApproveReject").Title(@Html.R("Status"));
})
.ClientEvents(events => events.OnComplete("onComplete"))
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it.
You can do it directly in the view, close to what you were thinking :

```
columns.Bound(model => model.IsApproveReject == 0 ? "Pending" : "Rejected").Title("Status")
```

Second way (which is cleaner) is to do it by creating a new property in your model (are you working with a view model by the way ? or directly with the model ?)
In the model :

```
public string Status
{
    get
    {
         return IsApproveReject == 0 : "Pending" : "Rejected";
    }
}
```

And in the view :

```
columns.Bound(model => model.Status)
```